# How do i can read all the files from aws s3 directory in a single poll using apache-camel

Tags: java, amazon-s3, apache-camel, spring-camel, apache-camel-aws

## Im trying to achieve :

1. Read all the files from the s3 directory.
2. copy all the files to backup directory on s3.
3. aggregate all the file contents to a single file and copy it to the 
   another directory on s3.

But Im stuck on the first point to read all the files in a single poll.

`my from router :
aws-s3://${camel.bucket.name}?amazonS3Client=#s3Client&prefix=some_path_on_s3&deleteAfterRead=true&delay=100s`

```
for example if, some_path_on_s3 -> has 2 files say first.txt and 
second.txt

according to camel documentation, it has to read both the files in a 
single poll, but is reading 1 file per poll.

I also tried with parameter,  maxMessagesPerPoll=2 but no luck. It 
still reads one file per poll.
```

Is there a way to fetch all the files from s3 directory in a single poll ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Truth is it sends one file at a time to the route, but it acknowledges the whole batch per poll.

maxMessagesPerPoll only creates a limit on the number of files read per batch. I think the information you are looking for is on the camel batch headers on every exchange:

CamelBatchComplete: A boolean indicating the last Exchange in the batch. Is only true for the last entry.

CamelBatchIndex: The current index of the batch. Starts from 0.

CamelBatchSize: The total number of Exchanges that was polled in this batch.

With this info you can multicast the message , then implement an aggregator to join the files on one route, once CamelBatchComplete=true,  and backup the files on another.

Find more info here:

[Batch consumer](https://camel.apache.org/batch-consumer.html)

[Multicast](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-spring/src/test/resources/org/apache/camel/spring/xml/buildStaticRecipientList.xml)

Comment: Hello @RaulCancino, 


    Thank you for your valuable response, That really helps!
    How do I can gather messages of the previous poll ?
   example, poll is at the index 3 and the CamelBatchComplete = true, How do i get the 
   messages of the previous poll(index 0, 1 and 2) to collate together ?

Comment: you have to use an agregation pattern as follows:

Comment: Let's call them "the previous exchanges of the poll".  You have to use an aggregation pattern [Component](https://camel.apache.org/aggregator2.html) everytime a exchange is processed, and the condition to fire the merge of the files is CamelBatchComplete = true,  [Code](https://www.sourceallies.com/2014/01/how-to-implement-the-splitter-and-aggregator-patterns-with-apache-camel/) [Pattern](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/Aggregator.html)

Comment: Thanks mate, really helpful.! CamelBatchComplete flag is the key.

Comment: @SuchethShivakumar please mark my asnwer as correct then.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- I got it working here,

  ```
  from("file://<some_path_to_dir>")
  .routeId("some_route_id")
  .to("backup_dir")
  .to("direct:aggregate")
  .end();



  from("direct:aggregate")
  .routeId("aggregate_router")
  .aggregate(constant(true), new GroupedExchangeAggregationStrategy())
          .completionPredicate(exchange -> {
              List<Exchange> list = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.GROUPED_EXCHANGE, List.class);
              Exchange latestExchange = list.get(list.size() - 1);
              return (boolean) latestExchange.getProperty(Exchange.BATCH_COMPLETE);
          })
  .to("direct:merge");


  from("direct:merge")
          .routeId("merge_router")
          .process(new Processor() {
              @Override
              public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                  List<Exchange> list = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.GROUPED_EXCHANGE, List.class);
                  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                  for(Exchange ex : list){
                      builder.append(ex.getIn().getBody(String.class));
                  }

                  exchange.getIn().setBody(builder.toString());
                  // set any other necessary header if required here
                  // example, if aws s3 is the endpoint, set the S3Constants.KEY header here
              }
          })
  .to("some_final_endpoint");
  ```